# JBPM 6 - in memory database

Tags: jbpm

Has anyone had any luck getting JBPM 6 to work with a in memory database such as hsqldb? I am trying to configure this under the latest version of JBoss. This is the first time using JBPM so I don't have alot of experience with it. I tried changing the persistence.xml and the standalone.xml but I am getting an error saying the database doesn't exist. Can anyone provide some config examples of this working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at the jbpm installer. We always use H2 (the new name of hsqldb) to work with jbpm so it's like the default database. The jBPM install is using it. 
Also you can check a test distribution that I've created yesterday for a workshop in barcelona -> http://salaboy.com/2013/12/10/drools-jbpm-workshop-barcelona-10th-dec-2/ 
Look at the slides as well that explains how the database is set up.

Hope this helps.